# Simple Custom condition on Build step is not applied on TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using TFS 2018 update 3, a step was defined to be executed only on scheduled builds., the custom condition was defined:

```
eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

A build was queued, Despite the fact that the variable Build.Reason = 'Manual'. the step was executed, then the condition was changed to :

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
```

The result was the same: the step is executed even in gated check-in and or manual builds.

Comment: Hmm... you're right. The condition is very simple. Have you tried `and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))`?

Comment: I just try, the behavior is the same

Comment: Also, I do this for my builds when I need to debug.  I had a build step to print environmental variables so I can see the actual variables like "Build.Reason" and more.  I add the step "Batch Script" with the command `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and argument `/c set` .  Please try that and see what you get for "Build_Reason" in the list of environment variables that are printed.

Comment: I included a powershell step to print the build reason variable: write-host "My build reason is: $env:Build_Reason" and it shows the proper value according the type of build, so the problem is not in the variable value

Comment: @XtianGIS another condition works for you?

Comment: I am going to try another condition and let you know, so far as a workaround, I create an if structure in a powershell step